# Serial COM port on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, serial-port

I'm thinking about creating EC2 instances that run industrial software. This EC2 instance should be able to receive data from Serial COM port. Is it possible to connect things like this, with eventually a serial tunneling or anything else ?

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer to this question.

1. Yes, absolutely, this is possible in theory.
2. ...but it might not be practical or possible for the specific purpose/application/device that you have in mind.

[Terminal servers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_server) are a simple illustration of the principle. Note that in this sense, I'm not referring to a Windows Remote Desktop "terminal server," but to the generic device commonly called a *terminal server* which, in its simplest form, is a physical device that speaks a serial protocol such as [RS-232](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232)  on one side, and TCP on the other side.  RS-232 is the wire protocol of a PC "COM" port.

But a computer, configured with appropriate drivers, can have a "virtual" COM port that appears -- to software on the computer -- as an interface just like a physical COM port, but the driver for that COM port, instead of providing the software with access to literal hardware is in fact managing a TCP connection, tunneling the send and receive bits from the COM port back to the physical port on the terminal server.

The terminal server could be an actual, dedicated terminal server device, could be a full size PC, a microcontroller with network capability, a Raspberry Pi with a USB-to-Serial adapter... there are a lot of potential variations.

Problems to consider:

A lot of older industrial software seems very poorly written.  This is my impression, anyway. The implementers, perhaps working at the edges of their expertise, having made certain design assumptions that work on physical COM ports but may not be compatible with such a deployment.  This is less likely to be true if the systems are newer, and run on a modern OS, but back in the early days of Windows and before, this was a real mess.

License key dongles, if present, might rely on peculiarities of physical COM ports that are difficult or impossible to virtualize.  The terms of the software license may constrain you from doing this.

Some equipment may be unnecessarily sensitive to the delay that is introduced by the distances involved.  There are, for example, 22 ms of round-trip time in the Internet path between one of my facilities and the nearest AWS region. At 9600-8-N-1 that is the time to transmit ~23 bytes, and that's *best* case -- the virtualization layer and encryption will add more.  The machine or the software may or may not be well-written enough to accept that kind of delay, which does not occur on a physical, local COM port.

If the machine is being *controlled* (not simply observed) then you need to absolutely ensure that you are not creating a safety hazard by separating the machine from its software through a virtualization layer.

"Sharing" control of a machine by software on multiple EC2 instances seems like it might be implied by your illustration, but this potentially adds an entirely different set of complexity.

In theory, yes, it's possible. I mean, even Windows remote desktop allows you to [share a local COM port](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770631.aspx) with the remote system, allowing remote software to access and control your local device.

In practice, this potentially requires a lot of attention to a large number of factors that vary by operating system as well as by the specific peculiarities of the devices and software in question.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 connectivity is through the network interface, so I don't think a direct connection like the one you are asking is possible.

However, if you are talking about industrial devices supporting automation, chances are you can use MQTT or at least a MQTT bridge. If that's the case, you can take a look at [AWS IOT Core](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/)

With AWS IOT Core you don't only get bidirectional connectivity between your devices and AWS, but also powerful analytics, device registry and management, and full integration with the AWS ecosystem.